# Genymotion Android Emulator Issue

Tags: android, windows-10, genymotion

Genymotion Android emulator just stopped working after updating my os to windows10. 
I restarted my system, eclipse etc., still it is not working.
How can i resolve this?

Comment: I upvoted this question and thought i'd comment why.  Getting android environ configured and emu's working has been the majority effort for my own personal android efforts.  These questions are useful and help the devs out, although it does appear he answered his own question, which I don't like.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps to resolve the issue

1. Uninstall Genymotion and Virtual Box.
2. Delete all the folders related to either Genymotion or VB.
3. Re install both of the softwares

Now, it has to run.